# Unity: Can't get reference to a class via getcomponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
    using UnityEngine;

    public class CartMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

    LevelManager LevelManIns;

    void Start () {

        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();

        spriteRenderer.enabled = true;

        (line25)LevelManIns = GetComponent<LevelManager>();

        Debug.Log("--" + LevelManIns.xy.X);
        //transform.position = LevelManIns.Tiles[LevelManIns.PortalGreen].GetComponent<TileScript>().transform.position;

        iTween.MoveTo(this.gameObject, iTween.Hash("path", iTweenPath.GetPath("cartPath"), "time", 3));
        }
      }
```

I get the error:

*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CartMovement.Start () (at Assets/scripts/CartMovement.cs:25)*

I don't understand why I can't get a reference to another script. Can anyone fix this. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that LevelManIns = GetComponent<LevelManager>(); is generating the error? becuase that can't generate an error. If it can't get the component it will return null. It must either be the line below (or above) or another line. All it says is that you are trying to call something that is null. My best guess is that the GameObject don't have LevelManager attached to it.

Comment: yes the levelmanager is another gameobject's script but I need to access some properties from this class. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the level manager is attached to another object (as you mentioned in the comments), one way is to reference that object through the inspector and then get the script from that object.

```
public class CartMovement : MonoBehaviour {

SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
// Make it public, so it is visible in the inspector, and drag and drop the object into that instance
public LevelManager LevelManIns; 

    void Start () {
        // No need to assign it here, just maybe check if it is assigned like so
        if (LevelManIns == null)
            // Error, this should be assign outside
    }
}
```